# PrimeFaces commandButton doesn't navigate or update

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I'am using Primefaces to make my app a little bit more beautiful. I noticed that `p:commandButton` and `h:commandButton` don't work the same way.

The `p:commandButton` calls the method and nothing else hapens. The `h:commandButton` calls the method and returns a navigation.

I have got trouble with redirecting after pressing the login button when using `p:commandButton`. How to deal with that?

---

I do have an update parameter:

```
<p:commandButton value="Login" action="#{login.login}" type="submit" update="msgs" />
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

`<p:commandButton>` needs one of the following to work correctly:

- the `update` attribute to list id's of components to re-render (for AJAX requests)
- the attribute `ajax="false"` to make a normal, non-ajax submit.

If you have neither, the button does per default an AJAX request with no UI feedback.

Additionally, I've had problems with neither option working when the surrounding `<h:form>` had an `enctype` attribute.

Comment: You want `ajax="false"` if you want to have a synchronous request with a navigation. As to the `update` parameter, see my comment in [one of your previous questions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4605118/jsf2-exeptions-while-submiting-to-bean) which you didn't respond to yet.

Comment: Sry, just forgot about that -.-

Comment: As to the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` issue, for that you need to ensure that you've configured the PrimeFaces `FileUploadFilter` as per the instructions in their User Guide.

Comment: @BalusC: Ah, and now I know where that `enctype` came from - the file upload turned out to be unnecessary, but the attribute stayed around to mess up things... Thanks!

Answer (score 31):

I think what Cagatay ment was:

Does **not** navigate the page:

```
<p:commandButton action="home.xhtml" value="Go Home"/>
```

Works (redirects the page):

```
<p:commandButton action="home.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" value="Go Home"/>
```

Works (redirects the page)

```
<p:commandButton action="home?faces-redirect=true" value="Go Home"/>
```

if .xhtml is your default postfix defined in web.xml:

```
<context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name>
        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

More info can be found in the primefaces forum, for example in [this discussion about navigation](https://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=2278)

I hope that helped a bit...

Answer (score 8):

You must use redirect if you are doing navigation and request is done with ajax.

Answer (score 4):

I am having a similar problem.

I am using primefaces and primefaces mobile and the navigation fails in Firefox when using 
`<p:commandButton>` with ajax="false" and action="find.xhtml?faces-redirect=true".

The only way I could make it work also in Firefox was by using `<h:commandButton>`:

```
<h:commandButton value="#{msg.find}" process="find" 
                     action="find.xhtml?faces-redirect=true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

none of the above solution worked for me.
You can still go for simple javascript

```
<p:commandButton onclick="window.location.href =home.xhtml"
                    style="height: 20px" type="button" title="title" icon="ui-icon-transferthick-e-w"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<h:commandButton 
                             styleClass="btn btn-primary-active upgrade" data-dismiss="modal" 
                             value="Upgrade Account" 
                             action="profile.do?faces-redirect=true&amp;tab=plan" 
                             oncomplete="$('#freeGiftModal').hide();" process="@this" partialSubmit="true" immediate="true"/>
```

I used the commandbutton to navigate to profile page, and its working fine for me.

Comment: Your answer isffectively not different from others and in a way it is worse. Besides it not beimg a `p:commandButton`, which with the right attributes 'just works' it containsttributes that are not valid for an `h:commandButton`, mor that one of the other answers