# Primefaces adding Button issue - Beginner

Tags: button, primefaces

I am trying to add a button using primefaces to a JFS page, and upon clicking it a method from a Java class should be called:

```
<p:commandButton type="submit" 
                 value="Test - Print Message" 
                 action="#{DataForm.Preference}" />
```

I get the primefaces button (the nice GUI), but when I click on the button the code from the java class `DataForm.Preference` is not executed.

I have used the attribute `action` in my code, and I don't think primefaces recognizes it, how should I call the method `Preference` from my `DataForm` class?

Comment: Already answered in here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639205/primefaces-commandbutton-doesnt-navigate-or-update

Comment: I don't understand how to apply it to my problem as it's discussing about page redirect and my problem is about calling a `java` method from the backend..

Comment: Please edit your question and provide more of the code from your page. Also, provide the complete source code for your `Preference` action method. By the way, Yasin is correct. If you read the answer to the question that he linked to carefully you will be able to solve this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think "preference" is your method Name. Seems like its a property. Why is your value static? What's the point of then using an action method?

Comment: The `value` will be the name of the button, and `action` will execute the corresponding java method.