# JSF 2.0 page navigation not working

Tags: jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm using JSF 2.0 in my web project. But navigation is not working properly, in my case. I think this problem arose due to changes in hierarchy of the files because action method is working fine. I'm attaching the snapshot to give idea about files' hierarchy.

[image]

If anyone could help to overcome this, I'll be very thankful.

Comment: are you aware of the the new feature of jsf2 to navigate without the use faces-config.xml like here ? http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/

Comment: Yaeh, I'm. I tried it, but not solved my problem.

Comment: add ajax="false" to you commandButton

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to add `ajax="false"` to you primefaces commandButtons in order to perform navigation or use the simple `<h:commandButton` ...

if you want to use primefaces ajax button , you should sue redirect then,

like this

```
 <p:commandButton action="home?faces-redirect=true" value="Redirect to home"/>
```

also look a t similar question over here:

[PrimeFaces commandButton doesn't navigate or update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4639205/617373)

Answer (score 1):

Upgrade to PrimeFaces 3.2. Then you'll be able to navigate by ajax. The update/render of `@all` was not supported before that version. If you can't upgrade, then you need to bring in the following JavaScript hack:

```js
var originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction = PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse;
PrimeFaces.ajax.AjaxResponse = function(responseXML) {
    var newViewRoot = $(responseXML.documentElement).find("update[id='javax.faces.ViewRoot']").text();

    if (newViewRoot) {
        document.open();
        document.write(newViewRoot);
        document.close();
    }
    else {
        originalPrimeFacesAjaxResponseFunction.apply(this, arguments);
    }
};
```

Put this in a `.js` file which you import in the very end of the `<h:head>` tag. E.g.

```
<h:head>
    ...
    <h:outputScript name="js/primeFacesAll.js" />
</h:head>
```