# No navigation happens when using a p:commandButton

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

Here is a Facelets file which is used to get first and last name and after that will go to the another Facelets file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

    <h:head><title>User Form</title></h:head>

    <h:body>
    <h:form>
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">
            <p:graphicImage value="resources/images/image.jpg" width="50%"/>

            <p:panelGrid columns="2" width="50%">
                <f:facet name="header">
                    User Form
                </f:facet>
                <h:outputLabel for="firstname" value="Firstname: *"/>
                <p:inputText id="firstname" value="" label="Firstname"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="surname" value="Surname: *"/>
                <p:inputText id="surname" value="" required="true" label="Surname"/>

                <f:facet name="footer">
                    <p:commandButton type="button" value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" action="construction"/>
                </f:facet>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

I expected to go to the `construction.xhtml` when I press the "Save" button, but nothing happens. How is this caused and how can I solve it?

Comment: Is this actual code? Because a) you're using a `commandButton` for navigation and b) your `inputText`s don't have a backing value. That said, try using a `h:commandButton` or `<p:commandButton ajax="false">` as explained [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4639230/785663).

Comment: thanks @mabi , when the user held down the save button the `under Construction` page must appear , because as you said it is not complete and it just the start of this program

Comment: Why exactly did you use `type="button"`?

Comment: thanks @BalusC, there is no special reason for that, when i saw that my command button dose not work i tried to use this

Comment: Well, it's causing the whole trouble. It generates in HTML output a `<input type="button">` which is a dead simple push button (usually to execute some custom JS) instead of the desired `<input type="submit">` which actually submits the form. Are you saying that you're facing **exactly the same** problem when you remove that attribute?

Comment: yes exactly the same problem

Comment: Are you absolutely sure? Are you familiar with basic HTML and HTTP? Have you checked the HTTP traffic monitor and the server log? When you remove it, then it should start firing an ajax request instead of doing absolutely nothing. Whether that ajax request would in turn trigger the navigation is just a second problem. You've there namely an input with `required="true"` without any faces message handler.

Comment: when i use `ajax="false"` it gives me `javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: Illegal Syntax for Set Operation`

Comment: Finally, an exception! A good exception is already a whole answer at its own. However, I can't explain that based on the code posted so far; you're not running the code as shown in the question.

Comment: Is that caused by having no `value` for the `inputText`? I have seen this when JSF assumed `value="#{null}"`.

Comment: @BalusC i just removed `type="button"` and add `ajax="false"`

Comment: Well, nothing in the code posted so far can throw that exception. I can easily explain in layman's terms why/how that exception is caused, but without a valid code snippet I can't point out what exactly in your code should be altered in order to fix that exception. Perhaps it's caused by code in the target page where you're attempting to navigate to? In any case .. You're better off posting an SSCCE.

Comment: my program consist of to main part , core part and ui part , in the ui part i just have 2 page , first page is what i posted in the question and the another page is construction page , and i have no `managedBean` class yet in this projcet

Comment: Is it the `construction` view getting properly displayed when you GET it in the browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are using `commandButton` you must do something like this:

```
<p:commandButton  value="Save" icon="ui-icon-check" style="margin:0" action="#{someBean.navigate}"/>
```

it means that you must use `managed bean`

and in your case you must use `button` instead of `commandButton`