# <p:commandButton> doesn't navigate

Tags: jsf, primefaces

In this simple page below, both the standard button and the PrimeFaces button trigger the validation and display the expected message. However, if there is no validation error, the browser navigates to nextPage.xhtml *only* if the standard button **Submit B** is used. Pressing **Submit A** just seems to alter the appearance of the page somewhat, and no navigation takes place.

```
<h:head>
   <title>Some Title</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
   <h:form id="form">
      <p:panelGrid id="panel" columns="2" border="0" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="1">      
         <p:outputLabel value="Enter Username" />
         <p:inputText id="username" size="20" label="UserName" required="true">
            <f:validateLength for="username" minimum="5" maximum="20" />            
         </p:inputText>

         <p:outputLabel value="PrimeFaces Btn" />
         <p:commandButton value="Submit A" action="nextPage" update="form"/>

         <p:outputLabel value="Standard Btn" />
         <h:commandButton value="Submit B" action="nextPage" />
      </p:panelGrid>
      <!-- <p:messages autoUpdate="true" /> -->
      <p:message for="username" />
   </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your Example working just fine for me. Using Primefaces 5.2 and JSF-Mojarra 2.2.0

Comment: If a request is done with AJAX and you need navigation, you need to use "redirect" as to `<p:commandButton action="nextPage?faces-redirect=true" .../>` or make a synchronous request with a navigation (thus, by setting the `ajax` attribute associated with `<p:commandButton>` to `false`).

Comment: @Tiny Appending `?faces-redirect=true` works fine, thanks. However I was hoping to not have to do that as I'd like the URL in the address bar to remain pointing at the main App. If users bookmark the resulting page it will get messy. I'm working on a larger app, I just posted a simplified page here to illustrate the problem. There should be a different solution, note that if the standard button is pressed, it works fine with a forward, no redirect takes place. I'm also curious as to why it works for @KishorP and not me, I'm on PrimeFaces 5.2 and Mojarra 2.1.9

Comment: The resulting page will no longer be bookmarkable, if the POST request sent is not redirected to the resulting page. If this is however, not required, then there is no option other than setting `ajax` to `false` making a synchronous forward (Browsers will warn against refreshing the page (F5)).

Comment: @Tiny I think the option that makes sense would be to fix my environment and make this work as expected. The standard button works fine with no hacks or compromises, the PrimeFaces button should do. It works for KishorP. If only I knew where to look though, any ideas appreciated.

Comment: I have just tested on PrimeFaces 5.2 / Mojarra 2.2.12. It does not function without modifying the example. In Google search results, I have just [found](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4640701/1391249) an answer from Cagatay Civici himself, "***You must use redirect**, if you are doing navigation and request is done with ajax.*".

Comment: Food for read: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3909267, http://stackoverflow.com/q/15521451

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the pointers. The code snippet above is simplified for clarity but in the real application, my ` <p:commandButton>` is submitting a form that registers a user. After the DB is updated, I want to navigate the user to an intermediate page that has a phone PIN validation. I don't want this page to be bookmark-able. Therefore using `?faces-redirect=true` is not appropriate. Doing `<p:commandButton ajax="false"` would force a whole page reload for displaying validation errors. I just want to make it work like the standard `<h:commandButton>` does, is that not possible?

Comment: Just conditionally render content on same view (e.g. dialog).

Comment: @BalusC You mean render the PIN validation page in a dialog? Then it gets messy if the user closes the browser and decides to do the validation next time they login. I can't believe I have to do all these hacks just to get the PrimeFaces button do the obvious thing that the standard button does out of the box, I find it really mind blowing. Let's look at this from a different angle: can I skin the standard button to look like the PrimeFaces button? How would I go about that?

Comment: Turning off ajax does just same as h:commandButton.